# How to use the class string of another class?

Tags: c#

I have 2 .cs file. One contains string and the other post the string. I want to use the string from the class but when i add "public" to the string, the code messed up. 
Here is the class file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
namespace DreamJ
{
    public class second
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            string content = webClient.DownloadString("https://example.com");
            string result = content.Replace("\"", " ");
            string more = result.Replace("},", "},\n");
        }


    }
}
```

I want to get the "more" to the main class file, example: a.Send(more) (can't show it). I'm new to c# so help me pls. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Define "messed up". What happened exactly? And how did you try to access the `public` string? How did the erronous code look like?

Comment: you want your method to return a value.  You should do a search on that.

Comment: You need to learn the basics using a book or an online tutorial, you'll find many by searching the web for C# tutorials or at least OOP programming with any language. You have multiple options: 1- return a value from a method 2- use a static or instance public Property. and Many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create more as a public member. Either that or return more from your function.

Solution 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
namespace DreamJ
{
    public class second
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            string content = webClient.DownloadString("https://example.com");
            string result = content.Replace("\"", " ");
            more = result.Replace("},", "},\n");
        }

       public string more
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
namespace DreamJ
{
    public class second
    {
        public string Test()
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            string content = webClient.DownloadString("https://example.com");
            string result = content.Replace("\"", " ");
            string more = result.Replace("},", "},\n");
            return more;
        }

    }
}
```